# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'

Tags: flutter, dart, classpath, sqflite

I install 'sqflite' and add 'sqflite: ^2.3.2' on 'dependencies' into "pubspec.yaml" as the following picture:

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJRFC.png)

My "andriod/build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```ini
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-1.11.4.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.11.4/bundletool-1.11.4.jar
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to modify the classpath of dependencies in the andriod/build.gradle file but I didn't get any results.

Flutter doctor is :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.1 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7f20e5d18c (3 months ago), 2023-11-27 09:47:30 -0800
    • Engine revision 22b600f240
    • Dart version 3.2.1
    • DevTools version 2.28.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.9.34607.119
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.82.0

[√] Connected device (5 available)
    • RNE L21 (mobile)             • FFY5T18410008930 • android-arm64  • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554    • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows          • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.69
    • Edge (web)                   • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 121.0.2277.128

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```